# How to get the class name of a method in Python?

Tags: python, class, printing, decorator

Here's my problem and the code:
I try to use a decorator to reecord the time cost; but I cannot get the class name.

```py
import functools
import time


def log_time(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def record(*args, **kwargs):
        # print(func)
        # print(func.__name__)
        # print(func.__class__)
        # print(func.__class__.__name__)
        func_name = func.__name__
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{func_name} costs time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f}s")
        return result

    return record


class FakeProject:
    @log_time
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.load_data = [i for i in range(value)]

fake_project = FakeProject(100000000)
```

above code has log message as `__init__ cost time: 3.65s`;

But I want the `FakeProject.__init__ cost time: 3.65s` instead.

How can I get the class name and print it? Anyone can help? Thanks anyway

I try to print

```py
print(func)
print(func.__name__)
print(func.__class__)
print(func.__class__.__name__)
```

and I get

```
<function FakeProject.__init__ at 0x0000022F3F365318>
__init__
<class 'function'>
function
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can just use the `__qualname__`:

```
import functools
import time


def log_time(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def record(*args, **kwargs):
        func_name = func.__qualname__
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{func_name} costs time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f}s")
        return result

    return record


class FakeProject:
    @log_time
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.load_data = [i for i in range(value)]

fake_project = FakeProject(100000000)
```

This outputs:

```
FakeProject.__init__ costs time: 5.26s
```